# Is a set of orbit representatives same as a set of coset representatives?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let G be a multiplicative abelian group and H $\subset$ G. Assume H acts on G by multiplication.

1. Is a set of orbit representatives of G under the action of H same as a set of coset representatives of H in G? If so, is G/H the correct notation for both the sets?
2. If G is a semi-group instead, is it legit to talk about a set of coset representatives of H in G? (As far as I know of, coset representatives arise from the equivalence relation defined on a subgroup of a 'group'.)

Comment: The answer to 1 is yes. If $H$ acts on $G$ by multiplication, then the orbit containing $g \in G$ is $gH = Hg$, which is also the coset containing $g$. However, the notation $G/H$ refers to the set of cosets (which equals the set of orbits in this case), not a set of representatives.

Comment: Thanks! Please refer to my comment below.

Comment: A set of orbit (or coset) representatives is sometimes called a transversal, but I'm not aware of any standard notation for this.

Comment: By the way, there is one subtlety if the group is not abelian. In that case, $H$ acts on $G$ by **left** multiplication: $h \cdot g = hg$, so the orbit containing $g$ is $Hg$, which is the **right** coset containing $g$. If $H$ is normal, then $Hg = gH$, but this isn't true in general.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the notion of "transversal". You are definitely right for the non-abelian group. In this case, the sets would not be the same. Fortunately, we could state that there would be four sets of representatives in the context: two from the left and right group actions and the other two corresponding to the left and right cosets. We could establish a bijection between any two of these four sets and hence, their cardinalities, if finite, would be equal.

Comment: In fact, following the point you mentioned, the set of orbit representatives of the group under the left action of the subgroup corresponds to the set of right coset representatives of the subgroup in the group.

Comment: Quick note: One should probably refrain from saying "THE set of orbit representatives" as using the definite article subtly implies that this set is unique (or at least that there is a canonical choice).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I shall definitely be careful next time onwards.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Is the set of orbit representatives of $G$ under 
the action of H same as the set of coset representatives of 
$H$ in $G$?**

Yes, but rather than write ***the*** set of orbit representatives, it is better to write ***a*** set of orbit representatives, since the representatives are not unique.

**If so, is $G/H$ the correct notation for both the sets?**

$G/H$ is the notation for the set of cosets. It is in bijection with any set of coset representatives, but not equal to a set of representatives.

**If G is a semi-group instead, is it legit to talk about the set of coset representatives of H in G? (As far as I know of, coset representatives arise from the equivalence relation defined on a subgroup of a 'group'.)**

It is not legit to talk about the cosets of a subsemigroup $H\leq G$. But it is legit to talk about the cosets of a semigroup congruence.

Comment: Thanks! So, is there a standard notation for such a set of representatives?

Comment: I don't know one.