# How can we define an orbit of a group (not element of the group)?

Tags: group-theory, definition

I'm having confusion when we say some group $Z$ is an orbit of another group $G$, while I only know the elementwise definition $Orb(g)=Zg=\{zg | z \in Z \}$.

What does "$Z$ is an orbit of $G$" mean?
And what's the result going to be?

I guess this implies that "for each $g,h \in G$, $Orb(g)=Orb(h)$." Is my guess correct?

P.S.

The problem I'm working on denotes $G$ as a subgroup of the isometry group of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $Z = \{(n,0) | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Orbit is defined as a sub group, in this subgroup, each element can be reached from another by multiplication by some element in the parent group/ all possible destinations of the elemnt under the group action

Comment: @Buraian So, when we say $Z$ is an orbit of $G$, we have $Orb(g)$ as a subgroup of the set of all cosets $\{Zg | g \in G\}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532430/is-a-set-of-orbit-representatives-same-as-a-set-of-coset-representatives

Comment: $Z$ is a subgroup of translations in the plane $\Bbb R^2$. So $Z\le {\rm Isom}(\Bbb R^2)$. We have $Z\cong \Bbb Z\times 0\cong \Bbb Z$.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going here. You say "$Z$ is an orbit of another group $G$" but then you write "$Orb(g)=Zg$". Either $G$ acts on $Z$, in which case it makes sense to talk about $Z$ being an orbit but then $Orb(z)=Gz$. Or $Z$ acts on $G$, in which case $G$ can be an orbit of $Z$ but not vice versa. Also in the last paragraph you talk about a subgroup $G$ of isometry group of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and some subset $Z\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. So it looks like $G$ acts on $Z$? Also why is it relevant that $Z$ is a group? The last paragraph seems to imply that it doesn't matter.

Comment: You should provide a reference and a direct quote that is in the author's own words rather than in your words.